# Agrupar objeto no javascript por categorias

Tags: javascript, jquery, table, datatable

Possuo um código com Datatable e queria agrupar e somar os valores em situações

```
  var table = $('#tabelaDadosFinanc').DataTable();

    var data = table
    .rows()
    .data();

    var total = 0;


    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        var valor = data[i]['valor'];
        var moeda = data[i]['moeda'];

        removeFirst = valor.replace('<span class="text-danger" id="negativo">','');

            valores = removeFirst.replace('</span>','');

            a = valores.replace('.','');
            b = a.replace(',', '.')

            total +=parseFloat(b);

    }
     console.log(total);
```

Precisaria Agrupar pelo tipo de moeda e somar os valores,

ex:
 como tenho hoje

```
Moeda |  Valor
Real  | -56,12
Real  | -48,54
AU    | -46,60
Real  | -46,60
Real  | -46,60
Real  | 46,60
Real  | 48,54
Real  | 56,12
```

para ficar assim no final

```
 Real| -46,60
 AU | -46,60
```

Comment: Vai considerar sigla da moeda e nome?

Comment: considero primeiramente a moeda - e agrupo os valores que pertencem a moeda ex: Real -> -46,60
 AU -> -46,60

Comment: Os valores no final do agrupamento não são esses por exemplo Real | vai dar outro valor?

Comment: o valor do agrupamento é a soma dos valores, total de real, total de Au

Comment: Mas Real é diferente de R$ que, por sua vez, é diferente de RS. A dúvida é, Real, R$ e RS são a mesma coisa?

Comment: Sim são as mesmas coisas

Comment: Felipe, só uma dúvida como converter isso (var valor = data[i]['valor'];
        var moeda = data[i]['moeda'];) em const data = [
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":-56.12},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":-48.54},
  {"moeda": "AU", "valor":-46.60},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":-46.60},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":-46.60},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":46.60},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":48.54},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":56.12 }
];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para fazer isso, basta fazer o seguinte:

```js
const data = [
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":-56.12},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":-48.54},
  {"moeda": "AU", "valor":-46.60},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":-46.60},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":-46.60},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":46.60},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":48.54},
  {"moeda": "Real", "valor":56.12 }
];

const resultado = {};

data.forEach(item => {
  if(resultado.hasOwnProperty(item.moeda)) {
    resultado[item.moeda] += item.valor;
  } else {
    resultado[item.moeda] = item.valor;
  }
});

console.log(resultado);

console.log("MOEDA\t| VALOR");
for(var moeda in resultado) {
  console.log(moeda+"\t| "+resultado[moeda]);
}
```

Caso você queira fazer uma tradução da moeda, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
const siglaMoedas = {
  "R$": ["Real","RS"],
  "AU$": ["AU", "AUD"],
  "US$": ["Dolar", "USD"]
};

function pegaSigla(nomeMoeda) {
  for(let sigla in siglaMoedas) {
    if(siglaMoedas[sigla].includes(nomeMoeda)) return sigla;
  }
  return nomeMoeda;
}

console.log(pegaSigla('Real'));
console.log(pegaSigla('AU'));
console.log(pegaSigla('USD'));
console.log(pegaSigla('Dolar Canadense'));
```

E utilizar o segundo script para substituir as partes onde tem `item.moeda` para `pegaSigla(item.moeda)`